# Scanning list with Java regex grouping

Tags: java, regex, list, grouping

I want to get the positions and lengths of the elements in a list. Therefore, I would like to use regex grouping because with that I'm able to get the offsets and lengths of the matched groups. The elements are separated with commas and are allowed to contain any kind of characters. Here's an example:

( 1234, A{}, "foo" )

Here is what I tried to do:

```
String textToMatch = "( 1234, A{}, \"foo\" )";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(\\s*([^,]+?)(?:\\s*,\\s*([^,]+?)\\s*)*\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(textToMatch);

if (m.find()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I only get the first and last element, but not the ones in between. Here's the output I get with the code shown above:

```
1234
"foo"
```

If I use the same regex three times instead of using the star operator it works. I guess I do something wrong with iterating through the groups. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know java regex very well, but: is there any reason you're going i from 1 to less-than-equal groupCount(), instead of 0 to less than groupCount()?

Comment: @mfrankli: Groups are 1-based, not 0-based. (This is standard across pretty much all regex engines.) In Java, group 0 is a pseudo-group that matches the entire matched substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than matching the whole string with a single call to `find`, I think you should create a regex that matches each list element, and then loop over those matches. For example:

```
// regex for any sequence of non-comma, non-parenthesis characters that
// neither starts nor ends with whitespace:
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^,\\s()](?:[^,()]*[^,\\s()])?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(textToMatch);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group()); // print entire matched substring
}
```